# Execute echo in windows as maven Dexec.executable

Tags: maven, maven-3

I need to make an echo in windows for the next sentence:

```
mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -q exec:exec -Dexec.executable="cmd /c echo" -Dexec.args='${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:'
```

The problem is that it detects it (-Dexec.executable="cmd /c echo") as multiple commands and returns the following error:

> "ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on
>   project openregt: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "cmd \c
>   echo" (in directory "C:\Users\hlor\Desktop\Test Senel\main"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the specified file ->
>   [Help 1]".

In linux it doesn't give me problems because echo is an executable and with just echo, it works correctly.

PS. Maven version:Apache Maven 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it with the command:

ECHO ON

- More info [here](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html).

As I need to run it inside a code in Golang, I set the variable through the command:

os.Setenv("ECHO", "ON")